# DR Site removed including 3rd DC before it was demoted

Tags: active-directory, domain-controller, windows-sbs-2008, disaster-recovery

I'm planning a migration from SBS2008 to 2012 Essentials, and Exchange 2007 to Online-Exchange. I have inherited a network structure like this, made up of 2 sites:

> **DataRec** Site - DC02 (Decommissioned)
>
> **HeadOffice** Site - DC01 (SBS2008) & DC03 (VMware)

Unfortunately the DataRec site was decommissioned a month ago before I inherited this setup, and the DC02 was not demoted.

As a result, I have some KCC issues and I'm not entirely sure about the extent of the rest of the domain partition yet. But user accounts and most (all?) of the policies seem to be in place, and no one is the wiser. In fact, I only picked this up after running DCDIAG.

My question is, if I manually remove all traces of the DC02 (including the site DataRec), update the DNS records, do I need to create another DC02 to replace it? Is AD now dependant on having 3 DC's in terms of replication? Or can I leave the 2 DC's as is, and then perform the migration reasonably safely?

Thanks for any advice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply delete the computer account for DC02 in active directory, then remove the site DataRec.

> When you use Remote Server Administration Tools (RSAT) or the Active Directory Users and Computers console (Dsa.msc) that is included with Windows Server 2008 or Windows Server 2008 R2 to delete a domain controller computer account from the Domain Controllers organizational unit (OU), the cleanup of server metadata is performed automatically. Previously, you had to perform a separate metadata cleanup procedure.

Source: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc816907(v=ws.10).aspx

There is no requirement to create a new DC02, in fact doing so would likely complicate matters.

You should also check that all FSMO roles remain on SBS 2008.

Afterwards I would advise checking DCDIAG again before commencing the migration.

Comment: Thanks BlueCompute for the perfect link, are you aware of any special considerations to watch out for? Can I confidently run this in a live environment?